# Enumerate the multiple rows in a multi-update Trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I have something like the table below:

```
CREATE TABLE updates (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1, 1),
    name VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    updated DATETIME
);
```

And I'm updating it like so:

```
INSERT INTO updates (name, updated)
VALUES
    ('fred', '2020-11-11),
    ('fred', '2020-11-11'),
    ...
    ('bert', '2020-11-11');
```

I need to write an after update Trigger and enumerate all the name(s) that were added and add each one to another table but can't work out how enumerate each one.

EDIT: - thanks to those who pointed me in the right direction, I know very little SQL.

What I need to do is something like this

- foreach name in inserted
- look it up in another table and
- retrieve a count of the updates a 'name' has done
- add 1 to the count
- and update it back into the other table

I can't get to my laptop at the moment, but presumably I can do something like:

```
BEGIN
  SET @count = (SELECT UCount from OTHERTAB WHERE name = ins.name)
  SET @count = @count + 1
  UPDATE OTHERTAB SET UCount = @count WHERE name = ins.name
  SELECT ins.name
  FROM inserted ins;
END
```

and that would work for each name in the update?

Obviously I'll have to read up on set based SQL processing.

Thanks all for the help and pointers.

Comment: Tip: Cursor or while loop. But if you are just adding to another table you hardly need to enumerate, a simple SQL insert handles sets of data. The official docs explain it all.

Comment: If you are planning to loop in SQL you likely already have the wrong plan. Iteration is one of the slowest things to do in an RDBMS; use set based methods.

Comment: You may want to use `distinct name from inserted` when you `update OtherTab`. Since the trigger will fire once per statement, not per row, the same name may occur several times.

Comment: I just can't get any of the suggestions to work - I have worked out how to do it with cursors - these fit my brain much easier , but i know they're frowned on. I have simplifed things greatly by putting the insert/update code into a stored proc. I think I should delete this question and put in a new one, asking how to convert a cursor based approach to a set based one.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your edits you would do something like the following... set based is a mindset, so you don't need to compute the count in advance (in fact you can't). It's not clear whether you are counting in the same table or another table - but I'm sure you can work it out.

Points:

- Use the Inserted table to determine what rows to update
- Use a sub-query to calculate the new value if its a second table, taking into account the possibility of null

If you are really using the same table, then this should work

```
BEGIN
    UPDATE OTHERTAB SET
      UCount = COALESCE(UCount,0) + 1 
    WHERE [name] in (
        SELECT I.[name]
        FROM Inserted I
    );
END;
```

If however you are using a second table then this should work:

```
BEGIN
    UPDATE OTHERTAB SET
      UCount = COALESCE((SELECT UCount+1 from OTHERTAB T2 WHERE T2.[name] = OTHERTAB.[name]),0) 
    WHERE [name] in (
        SELECT I.[name]
        FROM Inserted I
    );
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`inserted`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-inserted-and-deleted-tables?view=sql-server-ver15) and set-based approach(no need for loop):

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg
ON updates
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO tab2(name)
  SELECT name
  FROM inserted;
END
```